# Django sending xml requests at the same time

Tags: python, xml, django

Using the form i create several strings that looks like xml data. One part of this strings i need to send on several servers using `urllib` and another part, on soap server, then i use `suds` library. When i receive the respond, i need to compare all of this data and show it to user. The sum of these server is nine and quantity of servers can grow. When i make this requests successively, it takes lot of time. According to this i have a question, is there some python library that can make different requests at the same time? Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using PycURL or Twisted. These should have the asynchronous capabilities you're looking for.